# C Malloc to a Pointer Through Function Call Causes Bus Error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, bus-error

Due to my feeble understanding of allocating type memory to pointers, the following causes a bus error on the call to barrier_create ("hi" is never printed).

```
typedef struct barrier barrier_t;
typedef struct barrier *barrier_p;

barrier_p test_barrier_p;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    barrier_create(*test_barrier_p);
}

int barrier_create(barrier_p *barrier_pointer) {
printf("hi\n");
    barrier_p old_barrier, new_barrier;
    int count;
    old_barrier = (barrier_p) *barrier_pointer;
    new_barrier = (barrier_p) malloc(sizeof(*new_barrier));
    count = pthread_mutex_init(&new_barrier->lock, NULL);
    new_barrier->is_valid = VALID_BARRIER;
    new_barrier->counter = 0;
    new_barrier->release_flag = 0;
    *barrier_pointer = new_barrier;
    return HAPPY_HAPPY_JOY_JOY;
}
```

What am I missing or mis-typing?

Comment: As a minor nitpick: you don't normally "allocate pointers". You allocate storage, or memory, and then you get a pointer to that memory.

Comment: Thanks unwind. That is a helpful nit, and I switched my wording to reflect how I understand that.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but in general you probably should avoid doing things like `typedef struct barrier *barrier_p`.  Just use `barrier_t*`.  It'll be less confusing in the long run, and `const barrier_t*` and `const barrier_p` won't be the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
barrier_create(*test_barrier_p);
```

Since `barrier_create` takes address of a `barrier_p`, this should be `&test_barrier_p`, not `*test_barrier_p`.

```
printf("hi\n");
```

Inaccurate test of code reachability because stdout is likely buffered; I'd recommend `fprintf(stderr, "hi\n");` instead.

```
new_barrier = (barrier_p) malloc(sizeof(*new_barrier));
```

I'd say `sizeof(barrier_t)`.  Again a `*` in an odd place, the `_p` notation may not be helping your type manipulation clarity.

For pedanticism, I would check the return value of malloc.  I see little point in keeping the old value unless to recover in some way from a malloc error.

What is the purpose of count?

Comment: Also correct, but a little more complete a description. But I don't think it would be sizeof(barrier_p), wouldn't it be sizeof(barrier_t)?

Comment: yes, definitely sizeof(barrier_t). sizeof(barrier_p) will just return the size of a pointer (pretty much 4 or 8 these days).

Comment: yeah, old_barrier seems to just be leaking memory... maybe it was originally meant so that the barrier could be free()d after the global variable was set to the new barrier?

Comment: yeah, could be designed for freeing, assuming it's never passed an uninitialized mess.  this looks extracted from a broader api and adjusted to fit, to me.

Comment: Since you're curious, I'm cutting down a sample synchronization barrier implementation for testing using pthreads. This is the one method out of the larger implementation that I confused myself on. count is there for debugging purposes. [[http://docs.hp.com/en/B3909-90015/apas04.html]]

Comment: Another thought you might consider as you are delving through things like this: if you temporarily compile it as C++, the extra type checking in C++ will tell you what the problem is. I did this to double check myself before I commented earlier.

Comment: I disagree with using `sizeof(barrier_t)` instead of `sizeof *new_barrier` in general.  It's a common idiom in C, particularly if the casts to `malloc` are removed.  It prevents a silent bug at runtime if the pointee type changes without updating the `malloc` size.

Answer (score 7):

You're dereferencing a bad pointer in your main function. To get the address of the variable, you use the address `&` operator, not the dereferencing `*` operator. Rewrite main as:

```
barrier_create(&test_barrier_p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer. I'm giving it to feonixrift since he gave the bonus of pointing out my silly use of buffered print.

Comment: Also, thanks Miquella for that comment. That actually nailed down the problem exactly for me mentally.

Answer (score 0):

The `test_barrier_p` variable is a pointer to a `barrier` structure which is never being initialized, so it's set to NULL (since it's at file scope).

You're de-referencing it at the call from `main()` to `barrier_create()`.

For help beyond that, you'll need to tell us, in English, what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The function `int barrier_create(barrier_p *barrier_pointer)` takes a pointer as an argument. However, you a passing in an `actual barrier_p` in your main since you dereference it - `barrier_create(*test_barrier_p)`. I think you should be passing the address like `barrier_create(&test_barrier_p)`